# How to obtain length of XML childnodes

Tags: javascript, xml

My question is pretty simple. All I want to do is get how many **employee** tags are inside of the **employees** tag. My XML looks like this...

```
<employees>
   <employee>
      <name></name>
      <city></city>
   </employee>
   <employee>
   .
   .
   .
</employees>
```

I've been using this javascript to try to the length but it keeps coming up zero...

```
items=request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("employees")[0].childNodes;
alert(items.length);
```

Comment: Have you tried any other debugging? What is the value of childNodes?

Comment: Have you tried `items = request.responseXML.documentElement.childNodes;`?

Comment: @PaulS. `getElementsByTagName` would cause an error if `request.responseXML` were `null`.

Comment: @Asad, yep. @landogriffen, What happens if you `console.log(request.responseXML)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have nested employee tags, you could simply use:

```
request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("employee").length
```

Comment: @landogriffen You would have to assign `request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("employee")` to `items`, not `request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("employee").length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
items=request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("employee");
alert(items.length);​
```

Comment: Note: employee vs employees

Comment: Doesn't look identical to me and I didn't see his when I posted mine

Comment: You use exactly the same approach, but you're right, I didn't consider you might not have seen it.